How to use the duplex scan and OCR with Epson Stylus Office BX635FWD?
I use an old Epson Stylus Office BX635FWD. It supports the duplex scan. But in the settings of the scan software I don't find any config for the text recognition.
Is it possible / How to achieve the OCR and the duplex scan with the BX635FWD?

Your asking two different and unrelated questions and in any case both quite trivial. Duplex scanning, if actually available, is done trough the feeder and managed by the proprietary software. OCR requires specific OCR software and should be independent and unrelated to Epson's software. Proprietary bundled software may or may not provide that feature but typically not. There's no special setting other than "text" for better results. OCR software should work with any scanned or any other origin file.

ChanganAuto is correct: OCR and Duplexing are two unrelated features and are applied in different places, using different means.
OCR is not a feature of the device. You may find OCR included in certain higher-end business-centric scanners, but it is rare to find this feature on consumer-level scanners.
Duplex scanning IS a feature of the device because it requires a different hardware design than uniplex scanning.
To OCR an already scanned image, find and use another piece of software specifically for that purpose. Many mainstream products offer OCR as a feature of their products (OneNote, for instance). But there may also be software tools which are more focused in their intent and only OCR, or offer this feature among a small collection of capabilities.
